# Bind a subclass property to a GridViewColumn

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to bind a subclass property to a GridViewColumn.
I have a mother class M1 and 3 differents subclasses S1, S2 and S3.
The GridViewColumn is filled with objects of class M1.
I'd like to bind to the header of this GridViewColumn a property of S2 that isn't implemented in M1.

Could someone explain to me how to do that please ?

EDIT :

I've got this line :

```
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding _s2Attr}" Header="desc" Width="100" />
```

The GridView ItemsSource is filled with objects of class M1 but they are all S1, S2 or S3.

Comment: What if type of data context will be `S3` or `S1`, instead of `S2`?

Comment: If it was the wrong type of object, you'd get an error similar to this: `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SomeProperty' property not found on 'object' 'S3' (HashCode=3806203)'. BindingExpression:Path=SomeProperty; DataItem='S3' (HashCode=3806203); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bindings are not strongly typed, they are resolved via reflection at runtime on the concrete `DataContext` object. As long as your actual `DataContext` class is S2 then you can bind to it fine.

Comment: My ItemsSource is filled with objects of class M1 but they are all S1, S2 or S3 so does the binding consider it as M1 objects or as they real inherited class ?

Comment: Yes, they are the "real" (concrete) class.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information but do you have an idea about why it doesn't display anything ? I checked at the object instantiation if the values were set and they are...

Comment: Check your output window for binding errors, or use a tool like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to have a look at the DataContext when its running.

Comment: Also are you sure you're binding to a property? The code you've added looks like it's trying to bind to a field with the _ prefix?

Comment: Well, it refers to a class attribute defined like that :

public class S2 : M1
{
...
        public String _s2Attr{ get; set; }
...
}

Comment: Urg, I just ran the program again and it works now... Can't understand what changed... Anyway, sorry for this loss of time and thanks for your answers.